# SQL INSERT or UPDATE

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0

Following on from this: [SQL INSERT from SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411339/sql-insert-from-select) and the correct answer marked there.

I will need to be able to also check whether the row already exists, also by using the username. So would I delete and then insert or is there a better way?
And if it is delete, how do I say DELETE FROM table WHERE UserID = *do the username select here*
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If delete then you can use:

```
DELETE a FROM Avatar a LEFT JOIN User u ON a.UserID=u.UserID WHERE u.UserName='theusername'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `REPLACE INTO` instead of `INSERT INTO`.  If the UserID is specified and is the primary key for the table, this will overwrite the row whose UserID matches what you insert.

To answer your sub-question, it would be `DELETE FROM table WHERE UserID IN (SELECT UserID ...)`

Side note: StackOverflow is really not an appropriate venue for learning basic SQL.  If you read up *first*, your questions will be better and the answers correspondingly more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from the other question where you're doing an "insert from select", I assume you want to not insert the row that already have entries for the keys you're attempting to insert. I also assume that it's giving you some error like "duplicate key found".

With those assumptions in mine, the fix is simple: add the IGNORE keyword after INSERT, so you're query looks something like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE... //rest of query
```