# How to insert select statement of get the day name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, select, insert

I have create a table with

```sql
create table tblConsultationHour
(
    consultationID int primary key identity,
    cday varchar(50),
    cstartTime datetime,
    cendTime datetime
)
```

I want to insert value of the day name into cday, and i should know the day name from the cstarttime of date part. what i know on how to get the day name with this code

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw,'2011-10-26 12:35:29.123')
```

may i know how can i insert this on the fly ?
or is that possible to insert in this way ?

```
insert into tblConsultationHour values 
(SELECT DATENAME(dw,'2011-10-26 12:35:29.123'),'2011-10-26 12:35', '2011-10-26 14:35')
```

Comment: because two reply also correct and the computed script is better because i don't know such function is available =D i trust the auto compute script would be better while no need to insert the select code always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach to consider is a computed column:

```
 create table tblConsultationHour
    (
        consultationID int primary key identity,
        cday as DateName(dw,cStarttime),
        cstartTime datetime,
        cendTime datetime
    )
```

In your example, cDay is a redundant column.   As written, if someone changes the cStarttime value, they must also remember to update the cDay field.   While it might not occur or be an issue, it is something to keep in mind...

Comment: Thx for reminding, dude =D because it was stated in my assignment question so i have to do so @.@ i found your solution would be better but wondering, will the value change while the cstartTime field being edited ??

Comment: If the cStartTime field is updated, cDay will be updated as well.

Answer (score 2):

You were close:

```
INSERT INTO tblConsultationHour 
SELECT DATENAME(dw,'2011-10-26 12:35:29.123'),'2011-10-26 12:35', '2011-10-26 14:35'
```

Also check out this question for other examples: [SQL INSERT from SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411339/sql-insert-from-select)

Comment: Thx dude =D and well reference ^^